# Add new tab in product edit page in admin Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I'm trying to create a custom module that will add a new tab on product edit page, right under Basic Settings. Can someone provide an answer?

Comment: The content of the tab should be loaded with AJAX or is a simple content tab?

Comment: The content of the tab, will be loaded with AJAX.

Comment: I need to create custom module which consist menu, how do I  add a new tab to that menu

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[EDIT] this does not work anymore for magento 2.1

you can create you own module.
In this module, create a file called `view/adminhtml/layout/catalog_product_new.xml` with this content

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product_tabs">
            <action method="addTabAfter">
                <argument name="tabId" xsi:type="string">tab-code-here</argument>
                <argument name="tab" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Tab label here</item>
                    <item name="class" xsi:type="string">ajax</item>
                    <item name="url" xsi:type="helper" helper="[Namespace]\[Module]\Helper\Url::getUrl" />
                    <item name="group_code" xsi:type="string">basic</item>
                </argument>
                <argument name="after" xsi:type="string">product-details</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

then create the file `Helper/Url.php` with this content:

```
<?php
namespace [Namespace]\[Module]\Helper;

class Url
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface
     */
    protected $urlBuilder;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $urlBuilder
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $urlBuilder
    )
    {
        $this->urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
    }
    public function getUrl()
    {
        return $this->urlBuilder->getUrl('your_tab/url/here', ['_current' => true]);
    }
}
```

this will add the tab right after "Product Details" tab. To re-position it, play around with the parameters from the xml file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  If i want to add multiple fieldset and inside these some multiple checkboxes? I'm referring to the content of this tab.

Comment: you can add whatever you want in there, The ajax call can return any html you need. You just need blocks and templates.

Comment: Could you please confirm whether this code will work in latest version of Magento 2.1?

Comment: @VIPINAROY This code will not work on 2.1 because the product form is not generated with tabs anymore. It is built with ui components.

Comment: Could you please help me to implement the tab in my Magento 2.1 website?

Comment: @VIPINAROY. I would if I could. I need this for my module also and still haven't figured it out.

Comment: @Marius..thanks for this answer, i need to call phtml file into this tab..how?

Comment: Hi @Marius How can i show grid inside the phtml

Answer (score 20):

**

> Below code Specially for Magento 2.2.0 and above

**

`Vendor/Module/registration.php` put below code.

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Vendor_Module',
    __DIR__
);
```

add the **module.xml** file in `Vendor/Module/etc/module.xml` put below code.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Module" setup_version="1.0.0"></module>
</config>
```

Now create uicomponent form xml 
`Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/product_form.xml` put below code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="testingproduct">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Testing Group</item>
                <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">product</item>
                <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">data.product</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">2</item>
                <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="opened" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="ns" xsi:type="string">product_form</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <container name="testing_group">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <htmlContent name="html_content">
                <argument name="block" xsi:type="object">Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Tab\CustomData</argument>
            </htmlContent>
        </container>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

In Block `Vendor/Module/Block/Adminhtml/Product/Edit/Tab/CustomData.php` put below code:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Tab;
use Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;

class CustomData extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $_template = 'customdata.phtml';

    protected $_coreRegistry = null;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Registry $registry,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->_coreRegistry = $registry;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getProduct()
    {
        return $this->_coreRegistry->registry('current_product');
    }
}
```

In templates `Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/templates/customdata.phtml` put below code.

```
<div>
   <span><?php echo __("Some Custom Data");?></span>
</div>
```

Comment: can we add it like label and text box , and also is it possible to move into product details tab ?

Comment: yes, you can add it like label and text box.

Comment: How we can add render condition for specific product type using above method?

Comment: Can we disable this tab for new products?

Answer (score 11):

Magento 2.1 :-If you have magento 2.1, also use this code for simple tab add in product edit page.
Create Own module and put below code in **view/adminhtml/layout/catalog_product_new.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product_form">
            <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Tab\Welcome" name="product.welcome" as="custom-tab" >
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Product Welcome</item>
                        <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="opened" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">2</item>
                        <item name="canShow" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">fieldset</item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
    </page>
```

In block **Vendor/Module/Block/Adminhtml/Product/Edit/Tab/Welcome.php** put below code.

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Tab;
use Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;

class Welcome extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $_template = 'catalog/product/edit/welcome.phtml';

    protected $_coreRegistry = null;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Registry $registry,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->_coreRegistry = $registry;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getProduct()
    {
        return $this->_coreRegistry->registry('current_product');
    }
}
```

In templates **Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/templates/catalog/product/edit/welcome.phtml** put below code.

```
<div class="welcome">
    <?php echo __('Welcome !'); ?>
</div>
```

Now Check Product edit page. It's working perfect.

Comment: Hi @Patel i have used your code, but it is not working for me, module created but tab is not...can you help me

Comment: I think mistake in your code Priya, Because already i use this code in my custome module.

Comment: But i just used the same code in this post Patel...kindly let me know the version which you have used

Comment: I have used Magento 2.1, Which you have?

Comment: am using Magento 2.0.7

Comment: Ok, Now you ask new question in this community and put your all code.

Comment: did you work on Magento 1x?

Comment: the above one will work in product edit page, but I need to create custom menu and need to add a tab which contains form means what will i do with the above code in backend. Please provide me a solution.

Comment: how to save the form data in the custom tab?

Answer (score 1):

To add tab in magento version 2.1.0 use below code

create **vendor/module/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">   
    <virtualType name="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Pool" type="Magento\Ui\DataProvider\Modifier\Pool">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="modifiers" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="customertab" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="class" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Modifier\Customertab</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">200</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
    <type name="Vendor\Module\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Modifier\Customertab">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="scopeName" xsi:type="string">product_form.product_form</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

create file **Vendor\Module\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Modifier\Customertab.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Vendor\Module\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Modifier;

use Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductLinkInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductLinkRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Locator\LocatorInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Api\AttributeSetRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Magento\Framework\Phrase;
use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;
use Magento\Ui\Component\DynamicRows;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\DataType\Number;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\DataType\Text;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\Input;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Field;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Fieldset;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Modal;
use Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image as ImageHelper;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status;
use Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\AbstractModifier;

/**
 * Class Customertab
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 */
class Customertab extends AbstractModifier
{
    const DATA_SCOPE = '';
    const DATA_SCOPE_CUSTOMER = 'customertab';       
    const GROUP_CUSTOMERTAB = 'customertab';

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private static $previousGroup = 'search-engine-optimization';

    /**
     * @var int
     */
    private static $sortOrder = 90;

    /**
     * @var LocatorInterface
     */
    protected $locator;

    /**
     * @var UrlInterface
     */
    protected $urlBuilder;

    /**
     * @var ProductLinkRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $productLinkRepository;

    /**
     * @var ProductRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $productRepository;

    /**
     * @var ImageHelper
     */
    protected $imageHelper;

    /**
     * @var Status
     */
    protected $status;

    /**
     * @var AttributeSetRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $attributeSetRepository;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $scopeName;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $scopePrefix;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Price
     */
    private $priceModifier;

    /**
     * @param LocatorInterface $locator
     * @param UrlInterface $urlBuilder
     * @param ProductLinkRepositoryInterface $productLinkRepository
     * @param ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
     * @param ImageHelper $imageHelper
     * @param Status $status
     * @param AttributeSetRepositoryInterface $attributeSetRepository
     * @param string $scopeName
     * @param string $scopePrefix
     */
    public function __construct(
        LocatorInterface $locator,
        UrlInterface $urlBuilder,
        ProductLinkRepositoryInterface $productLinkRepository,
        ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
        ImageHelper $imageHelper,
        Status $status,
        AttributeSetRepositoryInterface $attributeSetRepository,
        $scopeName = '',
        $scopePrefix = ''
    ) { 
        $this->locator = $locator;
        $this->urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
        $this->productLinkRepository = $productLinkRepository;
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->imageHelper = $imageHelper;
        $this->status = $status;
        $this->attributeSetRepository = $attributeSetRepository;
        $this->scopeName = $scopeName;
        $this->scopePrefix = $scopePrefix;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function modifyMeta(array $meta)
    { 
        $meta = array_replace_recursive(
            $meta,
            [
                static::GROUP_CUSTOMERTAB => [
                    'children' => [
                        $this->scopePrefix . static::DATA_SCOPE_CUSTOMER => $this->getCustomerFieldset(),
                    ],
                    'arguments' => [
                        'data' => [
                            'config' => [
                                'label' => __('Customer'),
                                'collapsible' => true,
                                'componentType' => Fieldset::NAME,
                                'dataScope' => static::DATA_SCOPE,
                                'sortOrder' =>
                                    $this->getNextGroupSortOrder(
                                        $meta,
                                        self::$previousGroup,
                                        self::$sortOrder
                                    ),
                            ],
                        ],

                    ],
                ],
            ]
        );

        return $meta;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function modifyData(array $data)
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product */
        $product = $this->locator->getProduct();
        $productId = $product->getId();

        if (!$productId) {
            return $data;
        }

        $priceModifier = $this->getPriceModifier();
        /**
         * Set field name for modifier
         */
        $priceModifier->setData('name', 'price');

        foreach ($this->getDataScopes() as $dataScope) {
            $data[$productId]['links'][$dataScope] = [];
            foreach ($this->productLinkRepository->getList($product) as $linkItem) {
                if ($linkItem->getLinkType() !== $dataScope) {
                    continue;
                }

                /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $linkedProduct */
                $linkedProduct = $this->productRepository->get(
                    $linkItem->getLinkedProductSku(),
                    false,
                    $this->locator->getStore()->getId()
                );
                $data[$productId]['links'][$dataScope][] = $this->fillData($linkedProduct, $linkItem);
            }
            if (!empty($data[$productId]['links'][$dataScope])) {
                $dataMap = $priceModifier->prepareDataSource([
                    'data' => [
                        'items' => $data[$productId]['links'][$dataScope]
                    ]
                ]);
                $data[$productId]['links'][$dataScope] = $dataMap['data']['items'];
            }
        }

        $data[$productId][self::DATA_SOURCE_DEFAULT]['current_product_id'] = $productId;
        $data[$productId][self::DATA_SOURCE_DEFAULT]['current_store_id'] = $this->locator->getStore()->getId();

        return $data;
    }

    /**
     * Get price modifier
     *
     * @return \Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Price
     * @deprecated
     */
    private function getPriceModifier()
    {
        if (!$this->priceModifier) {
            $this->priceModifier = ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(
                \Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Price::class
            );
        }
        return $this->priceModifier;
    }

    /**
     * Prepare data column
     *
     * @param ProductInterface $linkedProduct
     * @param ProductLinkInterface $linkItem
     * @return array
     */
    protected function fillData(ProductInterface $linkedProduct, ProductLinkInterface $linkItem)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $linkedProduct->getId(),
            'thumbnail' => $this->imageHelper->init($linkedProduct, 'product_listing_thumbnail')->getUrl(),
            'name' => $linkedProduct->getName(),
            'status' => $this->status->getOptionText($linkedProduct->getStatus()),
            'attribute_set' => $this->attributeSetRepository
                ->get($linkedProduct->getAttributeSetId())
                ->getAttributeSetName(),
            'sku' => $linkItem->getLinkedProductSku(),
            'price' => $linkedProduct->getPrice(),
            'position' => $linkItem->getPosition(),
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve all data scopes
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getDataScopes()
    {
        return [
            static::DATA_SCOPE_CUSTOMER,
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Prepares config for the Related products fieldset
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getCustomerFieldset()
    {
        $content = __(
            'Related products are shown to customers in addition to the item the customer is looking at.'
        );

        return [
            'children' => [
                'button_set' => $this->getButtonSet(
                    $content,
                    __('Add Related Products'),
                    $this->scopePrefix . static::DATA_SCOPE_CUSTOMER
                ),
                'modal' => $this->getGenericModal(
                    __('Add Related Products'),
                    $this->scopePrefix . static::DATA_SCOPE_CUSTOMER
                ),
                static::DATA_SCOPE_CUSTOMER => $this->getGrid($this->scopePrefix . static::DATA_SCOPE_CUSTOMER),
            ],
            'arguments' => [
                'data' => [
                    'config' => [
                        'additionalClasses' => 'admin__fieldset-section',
                        'label' => __('Customer'),
                        'collapsible' => false,
                        'componentType' => Fieldset::NAME,
                        'dataScope' => '',
                        'sortOrder' => 10,
                    ],
                ],
            ]
        ];
    }


    /**
     * Retrieve button set
     *
     * @param Phrase $content
     * @param Phrase $buttonTitle
     * @param string $scope
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getButtonSet(Phrase $content, Phrase $buttonTitle, $scope)
    {
        $modalTarget = $this->scopeName . '.' . static::GROUP_CUSTOMERTAB . '.' . $scope . '.modal';

        return [
            'arguments' => [
                'data' => [
                    'config' => [
                        'formElement' => 'container',
                        'componentType' => 'container',
                        'label' => false,
                        'content' => $content,
                        'template' => 'ui/form/components/complex',
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'children' => [
                'button_' . $scope => [
                    'arguments' => [
                        'data' => [
                            'config' => [
                                'formElement' => 'container',
                                'componentType' => 'container',
                                'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/components/button',
                                'actions' => [
                                    [
                                        'targetName' => $modalTarget,
                                        'actionName' => 'toggleModal',
                                    ],
                                    [
                                        'targetName' => $modalTarget . '.' . $scope . '_product_listing',
                                        'actionName' => 'render',
                                    ]
                                ],
                                'title' => $buttonTitle,
                                'provider' => null,
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],

                ],
            ],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Prepares config for modal slide-out panel
     *
     * @param Phrase $title
     * @param string $scope
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getGenericModal(Phrase $title, $scope)
    {
        $listingTarget = $scope . '_product_listing';

        $modal = [
            'arguments' => [
                'data' => [
                    'config' => [
                        'componentType' => Modal::NAME,
                        'dataScope' => '',
                        'options' => [
                            'title' => $title,
                            'buttons' => [
                                [
                                    'text' => __('Cancel'),
                                    'actions' => [
                                        'closeModal'
                                    ]
                                ],
                                [
                                    'text' => __('Add Selected Products'),
                                    'class' => 'action-primary',
                                    'actions' => [
                                        [
                                            'targetName' => 'index = ' . $listingTarget,
                                            'actionName' => 'save'
                                        ],
                                        'closeModal'
                                    ]
                                ],
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'children' => [
                $listingTarget => [
                    'arguments' => [
                        'data' => [
                            'config' => [
                                'autoRender' => false,
                                'componentType' => 'insertListing',
                                'dataScope' => $listingTarget,
                                'externalProvider' => $listingTarget . '.' . $listingTarget . '_data_source',
                                'selectionsProvider' => $listingTarget . '.' . $listingTarget . '.product_columns.ids',
                                'ns' => $listingTarget,
                                'render_url' => $this->urlBuilder->getUrl('mui/index/render'),
                                'realTimeLink' => true,
                                'dataLinks' => [
                                    'imports' => false,
                                    'exports' => true
                                ],
                                'behaviourType' => 'simple',
                                'externalFilterMode' => true,
                                'imports' => [
                                    'productId' => '${ $.provider }:data.product.current_product_id',
                                    'storeId' => '${ $.provider }:data.product.current_store_id',
                                ],
                                'exports' => [
                                    'productId' => '${ $.externalProvider }:params.current_product_id',
                                    'storeId' => '${ $.externalProvider }:params.current_store_id',
                                ]
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ];

        return $modal;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve grid
     *
     * @param string $scope
     * @return array
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
     */
    protected function getGrid($scope)
    {
        $dataProvider = $scope . '_product_listing';

        return [
            'arguments' => [
                'data' => [
                    'config' => [
                        'additionalClasses' => 'admin__field-wide',
                        'componentType' => DynamicRows::NAME,
                        'label' => null,
                        'columnsHeader' => false,
                        'columnsHeaderAfterRender' => true,
                        'renderDefaultRecord' => false,
                        'template' => 'ui/dynamic-rows/templates/grid',
                        'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/dynamic-rows/dynamic-rows-grid',
                        'addButton' => false,
                        'recordTemplate' => 'record',
                        'dataScope' => 'data.links',
                        'deleteButtonLabel' => __('Remove'),
                        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
                        'map' => [
                            'id' => 'entity_id',
                            'name' => 'name',
                            'status' => 'status_text',
                            'attribute_set' => 'attribute_set_text',
                            'sku' => 'sku',
                            'price' => 'price',
                            'thumbnail' => 'thumbnail_src',
                        ],
                        'links' => [
                            'insertData' => '${ $.provider }:${ $.dataProvider }'
                        ],
                        'sortOrder' => 2,
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'children' => [
                'record' => [
                    'arguments' => [
                        'data' => [
                            'config' => [
                                'componentType' => 'container',
                                'isTemplate' => true,
                                'is_collection' => true,
                                'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/dynamic-rows/record',
                                'dataScope' => '',
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                    'children' => $this->fillMeta(),
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve meta column
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function fillMeta()
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->getTextColumn('id', false, __('ID'), 0),
            'thumbnail' => [
                'arguments' => [
                    'data' => [
                        'config' => [
                            'componentType' => Field::NAME,
                            'formElement' => Input::NAME,
                            'elementTmpl' => 'ui/dynamic-rows/cells/thumbnail',
                            'dataType' => Text::NAME,
                            'dataScope' => 'thumbnail',
                            'fit' => true,
                            'label' => __('Thumbnail'),
                            'sortOrder' => 10,
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'name' => $this->getTextColumn('name', false, __('Name'), 20),
            'status' => $this->getTextColumn('status', true, __('Status'), 30),
            'attribute_set' => $this->getTextColumn('attribute_set', false, __('Attribute Set'), 40),
            'sku' => $this->getTextColumn('sku', true, __('SKU'), 50),
            'price' => $this->getTextColumn('price', true, __('Price'), 60),
            'actionDelete' => [
                'arguments' => [
                    'data' => [
                        'config' => [
                            'additionalClasses' => 'data-grid-actions-cell',
                            'componentType' => 'actionDelete',
                            'dataType' => Text::NAME,
                            'label' => __('Actions'),
                            'sortOrder' => 70,
                            'fit' => true,
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'position' => [
                'arguments' => [
                    'data' => [
                        'config' => [
                            'dataType' => Number::NAME,
                            'formElement' => Input::NAME,
                            'componentType' => Field::NAME,
                            'dataScope' => 'position',
                            'sortOrder' => 80,
                            'visible' => false,
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve text column structure
     *
     * @param string $dataScope
     * @param bool $fit
     * @param Phrase $label
     * @param int $sortOrder
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getTextColumn($dataScope, $fit, Phrase $label, $sortOrder)
    {
        $column = [
            'arguments' => [
                'data' => [
                    'config' => [
                        'componentType' => Field::NAME,
                        'formElement' => Input::NAME,
                        'elementTmpl' => 'ui/dynamic-rows/cells/text',
                        'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/text',
                        'dataType' => Text::NAME,
                        'dataScope' => $dataScope,
                        'fit' => $fit,
                        'label' => $label,
                        'sortOrder' => $sortOrder,
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ];

        return $column;
    }
}
```

Comment: I need to create custom module which consist menu, how do I add a new tab to that menu

Answer (score 0):

I've did this by following Magento Reviews Module for Product.

```
    <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
        <body>
            <referenceBlock name="product_tabs">
                <block class="Namespace\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Tab\Mymodule" name="product.mymodule">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">My Module Title</argument>
                        <argument name="group_code" xsi:type="string">basic</argument> <!-- "advanced" for Advance Settings -->
                    </arguments>
                </block>
                <action method="addTab">
                    <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">product-mymodule</argument>
                    <argument name="block" xsi:type="string">product.mymodule</argument>
                </action>
            </referenceBlock>
       </body>
    </page>
```

Create Mymodule.php in your custom module as per given path.

Hope it helps.