# Magento-2.1.0 : add customer serialize grid to product edit page

Tags: admin, magento2.1.0, product-edit

I'm trying to create a custom module for Magento-2.1.0 that will add a new tab on product edit page in admin, with customer serialize grid.

Can anyone provide an answer?

I have already added tab to product edit page you can check my code in answer in [this question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/103642/add-new-tab-in-product-edit-page-in-admin-magento-2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add tab in magento version 2.1.0 use below code

create **vendor/module/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">   
    <virtualType name="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Pool" type="Magento\Ui\DataProvider\Modifier\Pool">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="modifiers" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="customertab" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="class" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Modifier\Customertab</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">200</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
    <type name="Vendor\Module\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Modifier\Customertab">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="scopeName" xsi:type="string">product_form.product_form</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
      <arguments>
          <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
              <item name="customertab_customer_listing_data_source" xsi:type="string">Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Grid\Collection</item>
          </argument>
      </arguments>
  </type>
</config>
```

create file **Vendor\Module\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Modifier\Customertab.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Vendor\Module\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Modifier;

use Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductLinkInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Locator\LocatorInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Api\AttributeSetRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Magento\Framework\Phrase;
use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;
use Magento\Ui\Component\DynamicRows;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\DataType\Number;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\DataType\Text;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\Input;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Field;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Fieldset;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Modal;
use Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image as ImageHelper;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status;
use Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\AbstractModifier;
use Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer\CollectionFactory;

/**
 * Class Customertab
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 */
class Customertab extends AbstractModifier
{
    const DATA_SCOPE = '';
    const DATA_SCOPE_CUSTOMER = 'customertab';
    const GROUP_CUSTOMERTAB = 'customertab';

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private static $previousGroup = 'search-engine-optimization';

    /**
     * @var int
     */
    private static $sortOrder = 90;

    /**
     * @var LocatorInterface
     */
    protected $locator;

    /**
     * @var UrlInterface
     */
    protected $urlBuilder;

    /**
     * @var ProductLinkRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $productLinkRepository;

    /**
     * @var ProductRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $CustomerInterface;

    /**
     * @var ImageHelper
     */
    protected $imageHelper;

    /**
     * @var Status
     */
    protected $status;

    /**
     * @var AttributeSetRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $attributeSetRepository;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $scopeName;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $scopePrefix;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Price
     */
    private $priceModifier;

    private $collectionFactory;

    /**
     * @param LocatorInterface $locator
     * @param UrlInterface $urlBuilder
     * @param ProductLinkRepositoryInterface $productLinkRepository
     * @param ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
     * @param ImageHelper $imageHelper
     * @param Status $status
     * @param AttributeSetRepositoryInterface $attributeSetRepository
     * @param string $scopeName
     * @param string $scopePrefix
     */
    public function __construct(
        LocatorInterface $locator,
        UrlInterface $urlBuilder,       
        CustomerInterface $CustomerInterface,
        ImageHelper $imageHelper,
        Status $status,
        AttributeSetRepositoryInterface $attributeSetRepository,
        CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
        $scopeName = '',
        $scopePrefix = ''
    ) { 
        $this->locator = $locator;
        $this->urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
        // $this->productLinkRepository = $productLinkRepository;
        $this->CustomerInterface = $CustomerInterface;
        $this->imageHelper = $imageHelper;
        $this->status = $status;
        $this->attributeSetRepository = $attributeSetRepository;
        $this->scopeName = $scopeName;
        $this->scopePrefix = $scopePrefix;
        $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function modifyMeta(array $meta)
    { 
        $meta = array_replace_recursive(
            $meta,
            [
                static::GROUP_CUSTOMERTAB => [
                    'children' => [
                        $this->scopePrefix . static::DATA_SCOPE_CUSTOMER => $this->getCustomerFieldset(),
                    ],
                    'arguments' => [
                        'data' => [
                            'config' => [
                                'label' => __('Customer'),
                                'collapsible' => true,
                                'componentType' => Fieldset::NAME,
                                'dataScope' => static::DATA_SCOPE,
                                'sortOrder' =>
                                    $this->getNextGroupSortOrder(
                                        $meta,
                                        self::$previousGroup,
                                        self::$sortOrder
                                    ),
                            ],
                        ],

                    ],
                ],
            ]
        );

        return $meta;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function modifyData(array $data)
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product */
        $product = $this->locator->getProduct();
        $productId = $product->getId();

        if (!$productId) {
            return $data;
        }

        $customer = $this->CustomerInterface->getId();
        $collection = $this->collectionFactory->create();
        foreach ($this->getDataScopes() as $dataScope) { 

            $data[$productId]['links'][$dataScope] = [];
            foreach ($collection as $linkItem) {
                // if ($linkItem->getLinkType() !== $dataScope) {
                    // continue;
                // }

                // /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $linkedProduct */
                // $linkedProduct = $this->productRepository->get(
                    // $linkItem->getLinkedProductSku(),
                    // false,
                    // $this->locator->getStore()->getId()
                // );
                $data[$productId]['links'][$dataScope][] = $this->fillData($linkItem);
            }
            // if (!empty($data[$productId]['links'][$dataScope])) {
                // $dataMap = $priceModifier->prepareDataSource([
                    // 'data' => [
                        // 'items' => $data[$productId]['links'][$dataScope]
                    // ]
                // ]);
                // $data[$productId]['links'][$dataScope] = $dataMap['data']['items'];
            // }
        } 

        $data[$productId][self::DATA_SOURCE_DEFAULT]['current_product_id'] = $productId;
        $data[$productId][self::DATA_SOURCE_DEFAULT]['current_store_id'] = $this->locator->getStore()->getId();

        return $data;
    }


    /**
     * Prepare data column
     *
     * @param ProductInterface $linkedProduct
     * @param ProductLinkInterface $linkItem
     * @return array
     */
    protected function fillData($linkItem)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $linkItem->getId(),            
            'name' => $linkItem->getName(),            
            'email' => $linkItem->getEmail(),           
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve all data scopes
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getDataScopes()
    {
        return [
            static::DATA_SCOPE_CUSTOMER,
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Prepares config for the Related products fieldset
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getCustomerFieldset()
    {
        $content = __(
            'This products are shown to customers in addition to the item the customer is looking at.'
        );

        return [
            'children' => [
                'button_set' => $this->getButtonSet(
                    $content,
                    __('Add Specific Customer'),
                    $this->scopePrefix . static::DATA_SCOPE_CUSTOMER
                ),
                'modal' => $this->getGenericModal(
                    __('Add Specific Customer'),
                    $this->scopePrefix . static::DATA_SCOPE_CUSTOMER
                ),
                static::DATA_SCOPE_CUSTOMER => $this->getGrid($this->scopePrefix . static::DATA_SCOPE_CUSTOMER),
            ],
            'arguments' => [
                'data' => [
                    'config' => [
                        'additionalClasses' => 'admin__fieldset-section',
                        'label' => __('Customer'),
                        'collapsible' => false,
                        'componentType' => Fieldset::NAME,
                        'dataScope' => '',
                        'sortOrder' => 10,
                    ],
                ],
            ]
        ];
    }


    /**
     * Retrieve button set
     *
     * @param Phrase $content
     * @param Phrase $buttonTitle
     * @param string $scope
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getButtonSet(Phrase $content, Phrase $buttonTitle, $scope)
    {
        $modalTarget = $this->scopeName . '.' . static::GROUP_CUSTOMERTAB . '.' . $scope . '.modal';

        return [
            'arguments' => [
                'data' => [
                    'config' => [
                        'formElement' => 'container',
                        'componentType' => 'container',
                        'label' => false,
                        'content' => $content,
                        'template' => 'ui/form/components/complex',
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'children' => [
                'button_' . $scope => [
                    'arguments' => [
                        'data' => [
                            'config' => [
                                'formElement' => 'container',
                                'componentType' => 'container',
                                'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/components/button',
                                'actions' => [
                                    [
                                        'targetName' => $modalTarget,
                                        'actionName' => 'toggleModal',
                                    ],
                                    [
                                        'targetName' => $modalTarget . '.' . $scope . '_customer_listing',
                                        'actionName' => 'render',
                                    ]
                                ],
                                'title' => $buttonTitle,
                                'provider' => null,
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],

                ],
            ],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Prepares config for modal slide-out panel
     *
     * @param Phrase $title
     * @param string $scope
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getGenericModal(Phrase $title, $scope)
    {
        $listingTarget = $scope . '_customer_listing';


        $modal = [
            'arguments' => [
                'data' => [
                    'config' => [
                        'componentType' => Modal::NAME,
                        'dataScope' => '',
                        'options' => [
                            'title' => $title,
                            'buttons' => [
                                [
                                    'text' => __('Cancel'),
                                    'actions' => [
                                        'closeModal'
                                    ]
                                ],
                                [
                                    'text' => __('Add Selected Customers'),
                                    'class' => 'action-primary',
                                    'actions' => [
                                        [
                                            'targetName' => 'index = ' . $listingTarget,
                                            'actionName' => 'save'
                                        ],
                                        'closeModal'
                                    ]
                                ],
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'children' => [
                $listingTarget => [
                    'arguments' => [
                        'data' => [
                            'config' => [
                                'autoRender' => false,
                                'componentType' => 'insertListing',
                                'dataScope' => $listingTarget,
                                'externalProvider' => $listingTarget . '.' . $listingTarget . '_data_source',
                                'selectionsProvider' => $listingTarget . '.' . $listingTarget . '.customer_columns.ids',
                                'ns' => $listingTarget,
                                'render_url' => $this->urlBuilder->getUrl('mui/index/render'),
                                'realTimeLink' => true,
                                'dataLinks' => [
                                    'imports' => false,
                                    'exports' => true
                                ],
                                'behaviourType' => 'simple',
                                'externalFilterMode' => true,
                                'imports' => [
                                    'productId' => '${ $.provider }:data.product.current_product_id',
                                    'storeId' => '${ $.provider }:data.product.current_store_id',
                                ],
                                'exports' => [
                                    'productId' => '${ $.externalProvider }:params.current_product_id',
                                    'storeId' => '${ $.externalProvider }:params.current_store_id',
                                ]
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ];

        return $modal;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve grid
     *
     * @param string $scope
     * @return array
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
     */
    protected function getGrid($scope)
    {
        $dataProvider = $scope . '_customer_listing';
        return [
            'arguments' => [
                'data' => [
                    'config' => [
                        'additionalClasses' => 'admin__field-wide',
                        'componentType' => DynamicRows::NAME,
                        'label' => null,
                        'columnsHeader' => false,
                        'columnsHeaderAfterRender' => true,
                        'renderDefaultRecord' => false,
                        'template' => 'ui/dynamic-rows/templates/grid',
                        'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/dynamic-rows/dynamic-rows-grid',
                        'addButton' => false,
                        'recordTemplate' => 'record',
                        'dataScope' => 'data.links',
                        'deleteButtonLabel' => __('Remove'),
                        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
                        'map' => [
                            'id' => 'entity_id',
                            'name' => 'name',
                            'email' => 'email',
                        ],
                        'links' => [
                            'insertData' => '${ $.provider }:${ $.dataProvider }'
                        ],
                        'sortOrder' => 2,
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'children' => [
                'record' => [
                    'arguments' => [
                        'data' => [
                            'config' => [
                                'componentType' => 'container',
                                'isTemplate' => true,
                                'is_collection' => true,
                                'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/dynamic-rows/record',
                                'dataScope' => '',
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                    'children' => $this->fillMeta(),
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve meta column
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function fillMeta()
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->getTextColumn('id', false, __('ID'), 0),            
            'name' => $this->getTextColumn('name', false, __('Name'), 20),
            'email' => $this->getTextColumn('email', true, __('Email'), 30),
            'actionDelete' => [
                'arguments' => [
                    'data' => [
                        'config' => [
                            'additionalClasses' => 'data-grid-actions-cell',
                            'componentType' => 'actionDelete',
                            'dataType' => Text::NAME,
                            'label' => __('Actions'),
                            'sortOrder' => 70,
                            'fit' => true,
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ],            
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve text column structure
     *
     * @param string $dataScope
     * @param bool $fit
     * @param Phrase $label
     * @param int $sortOrder
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getTextColumn($dataScope, $fit, Phrase $label, $sortOrder)
    {
        $column = [
            'arguments' => [
                'data' => [
                    'config' => [
                        'componentType' => Field::NAME,
                        'formElement' => Input::NAME,
                        'elementTmpl' => 'ui/dynamic-rows/cells/text',
                        'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/text',
                        'dataType' => Text::NAME,
                        'dataScope' => $dataScope,
                        'fit' => $fit,
                        'label' => $label,
                        'sortOrder' => $sortOrder,
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ];

        return $column;
    }
}
```

Create **app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/customertab_customer_listing.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">customertab_customer_listing.customertab_customer_listing_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">customertab_customer_listing.customertab_customer_listing_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="spinner" xsi:type="string">customer_columns</item>
    </argument>
    <dataSource name="customertab_customer_listing_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\DataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">customertab_customer_listing_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">entity_id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
                    <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="cacheRequests" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>
    <columns name="customer_columns" class="Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="fieldAction" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">customertab_customer_listing.customertab_customer_listing.customer_columns_editor</item>
                        <item name="target" xsi:type="string">selectCustomer</item>
                        <item name="params" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="0" xsi:type="string">${ $.$data.rowIndex }</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <selectionsColumn name="ids">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">entity_id</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">0</item>
                    <item name="preserveSelectionsOnFilter" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </selectionsColumn>
        <column name="entity_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">textRange</item>
                    <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">asc</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">ID</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
       <column name="name">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Name</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">30</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="email">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="editor" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Email</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">40</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```