# How to create a custom product tab in admin panel of Magento 2.1?

Tags: magento-2.1

I want to create a custom tab in back-end product edit module of Magento 2.1. Like this

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ih8Wb.png]

I tried [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/126777/14750) and tried to know how Magento adds these tabs. But didn't find a solution.

Please help me find the correct solution.

Comment: Have a look at http://www.ibnab.com/en/blog/magento-2/magento-2-backend-create-custom-tab-in-customer-view-and-load-grid-inside-admin

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add new tab in product edit page in admin Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/103642/add-new-tab-in-product-edit-page-in-admin-magento-2)

Answer (score 3):

Magento 2.1 :- You can use this code for simple custom tab add in product edit page. Create Own module and put below code in **Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/layout/catalog_product_new.xml**

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product_form">
            <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Tab\Welcome" name="product.welcome" as="custom-tab" >
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Product Welcome</item>
                        <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="opened" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">2</item>
                        <item name="canShow" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">fieldset</item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

In block **Vendor/Module/Block/Adminhtml/Product/Edit/Tab/Welcome.php** put below code.

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Tab;
use Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;

class Welcome extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $_template = 'catalog/product/edit/welcome.phtml';

    protected $_coreRegistry = null;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Registry $registry,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->_coreRegistry = $registry;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getProduct()
    {
        return $this->_coreRegistry->registry('current_product');
    }
}
```

In templates **Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/templates/catalog/product/edit/welcome.phtml** put below code.

```
<div class="welcome">
    <?php echo __('Welcome !'); ?>
</div>
```

Now Check back-end product module of Magento 2.1. It's working perfect.

Comment: You can check also this link for more help. http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/103642/add-new-tab-in-product-edit-page-in-admin-magento-2/128759#128759

Comment: Thanks.. it works. What if i need to save custom fields for particular product?

Comment: @PayalPatel nice solution

Answer (score 2):

Create the `di.xml` in adminhtml scope:

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/adminhtml/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <virtualType name="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Pool">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="modifiers" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="mageworx-option-dependency" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="class" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Name</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">71</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
</config>
```

Then add your `Vendor\Module\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Name`:

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier/Name.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Locator\LocatorInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\AbstractModifier;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\ArrayManager;
use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Container;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Fieldset;

class Name extends AbstractModifier
{

    const SAMPLE_FIELDSET_NAME = 'custom_fieldset';
    const SAMPLE_FIELD_NAME = 'sample_field';

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Locator\LocatorInterface
     */
    protected $locator;

    /**
     * @var ArrayManager
     */
    protected $arrayManager;

    /**
     * @var UrlInterface
     */
    protected $urlBuilder;

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $meta = [];

    /**
     * @param LocatorInterface $locator
     * @param ArrayManager $arrayManager
     * @param UrlInterface $urlBuilder
     */
    public function __construct(
        LocatorInterface $locator,
        ArrayManager $arrayManager,
        UrlInterface $urlBuilder
    ) {
        $this->locator = $locator;
        $this->arrayManager = $arrayManager;
        $this->urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
    }

    public function modifyData(array $data)
    {
        return array_replace_recursive(
            $data,
            [
                $this->locator->getProduct()->getId() => [
                    static::DATA_SOURCE_DEFAULT => [
                        static::SAMPLE_FIELD_NAME => $this->locator->getProduct()->getData(static::SAMPLE_FIELD_NAME),
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        );
    }

    public function modifyMeta(array $meta)
    {
        $this->meta = $meta;
        $this->addFieldset();

        return $this->meta;
    }

    protected function addFieldset()
    {
        $this->meta = array_replace_recursive(
            $this->meta,
            [
                static::SAMPLE_FIELDSET_NAME => [
                    'arguments' => [
                        'data' => [
                            'config' => [
                                'label' => __('Sample Fieldset'),
                                'componentType' => Fieldset::NAME,
                                'dataScope' => 'data.product',
                                'collapsible' => true,
                                'sortOrder' => 10,
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                    'children' => [
                        'header_container' => $this->getHeaderContainerConfig(10),
                        // Add children here
                    ],
                ],
            ]
        );

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get config for header container
     *
     * @param int $sortOrder
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getHeaderContainerConfig($sortOrder)
    {
        return [
            'arguments' => [
                'data' => [
                    'config' => [
                        'label' => null,
                        'formElement' => Container::NAME,
                        'componentType' => Container::NAME,
                        'sortOrder' => $sortOrder,
                        'content' => __('Sample content.'),
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'children' => [
                'sample_container' => $this->getSampleContainer(10),
            ],
        ];
    }

    protected function getSampleContainer($sortOrder)
    {
        return [
            'arguments' => [
                'data' => [
                    'config' => [
                        'label' => null,
                        'formElement' => Fieldset::NAME,
                        'componentType' => Fieldset::NAME,
                        'sortOrder' => $sortOrder,
                        'additionalClasses' => 'admin__field-wide',
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'children' => [
                static::SAMPLE_FIELD_NAME => $this->getSampleFieldConfig(10)
            ],
        ];
    }

    protected function getSampleFieldConfig($sortOrder)
    {
        return [
            'arguments' => [
                'data' => [
                    'config' => [
                        'label' => __('Sample Field'),
                        'componentType' => \Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Field::NAME,
                        'formElement' => \Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\Input::NAME,
                        'dataScope' => static::SAMPLE_FIELD_NAME,
                        'dataType' => \Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\DataType\Text::NAME,
                        'sortOrder' => $sortOrder,
                        'validation' => [
                            'letters-with-basic-punc' => true,
                        ],
                        'required' => true,
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'children' => [],
        ];
    }
}
```

Your new empty fieldset with example field:

[image: example fieldset with field]

Validation is working:

[image: validation is working]

When saving a product your data will be automatically applied to it:

[image: save debug]

See: `\Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Initialization\Helper::initializeFromData()`. Thus if the product has the respective field, then your value will be saved. Another way you need to use an observer or some kind of plugins (before the product saving process).

You can take more examples from:

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier

To get the current product you can use the `$this->locator->getProduct()`.

Comment: I didn't understand what is `Name` field in Dependency.php? and do i need to create a separate `name` class?

Comment: @HungryDB Name - is a modifier class name (`Dependency.php` should be the `Name.php`, it's a typo, sorry). So you need to create `app/code/Vendor/Module/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier/Name.php` with a namespace `Vendor\Module\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier` and a class name `Name`.

Comment: @HungryDB I've updated the code (updates `modifyData` method; adds constants). I can share a full example from the my module, but there a lot of code (more than 1k lines only in modifier).

Comment: @SiarheyUchukhlebau, Thanks for your great guide... how can I have two columns under sample fieldset?