# How to save custom product tab checkbox value in database using Magento 2

Tags: magento2, module, database, custom-options

I created my custom tab in product page. Now i did't found any solution to save custom tab value so that i can use that value on frontend.

I created custom tab on product page by creating catalog_product_new.xml file in /vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/adminhtml/layout/. Below is the code:-

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
            <!--
            /**
             * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
             * See COPYING.txt for license details.
             */
            -->
            <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
                <update handle="styles"/>
                <head>
                    <css src="jquery/fileUploader/css/jquery.fileupload-ui.css"/>
                </head>
                <update handle="editor"/>
                <update handle="catalog_product_form"/>
                 <referenceBlock name="product_form">
                       <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Tab\Welcome" name="product.welcome" as="custom-tab" >

                            <arguments>
                                <argument name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Product Finder Parts</item>
                                    <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                    <item name="opened" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">2</item>
                                    <item name="canShow" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                    <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">fieldset</item>
                                </argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </block>
                    </referenceBlock>
            </page>
```

Then i created block: Vendor/Module/Block/Adminhtml/Product/Edit/Tab/Welcome.php

```
<?php

    namespace Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Tab;
    use Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context;
    use Magento\Framework\Registry;

    class Welcome extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
    {
        protected $_template = 'catalog/product/edit/welcome.phtml';

        protected $_coreRegistry = null;

        public function __construct(
            Context $context,
            Registry $registry,
            array $data = []
        )
        {
            $this->_coreRegistry = $registry;
            parent::__construct($context, $data);
        }

        public function getProduct()
        {
            // return $this->_coreRegistry->registry('current_product');

            return "heloo dgdgdg";
        }


    }
    ?>
```

After that i created phtml file in Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/templates/catalog/product/edit/welcome.phtml

```
<div class="welcome">
        <div class="admin__field admin__field-option">
            <input type="checkbox" class="admin__control-checkbox" id="finder" name="_ids][1]" value="1">

            <label class="admin__field-label" data-bind="attr: {for: uid}, text: description" for="UVHR95L">Parts Finder Enable</label>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I have created tab in admin successfully by this code .

I tried [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/131527/how-to-create-a-custom-product-tab-in-admin-panel-of-magento-2-1/#answer-131548) but it didn't work for me.
Can you guys help me to save this value? I am searching for solution from past 2 days.

Answer (score 2):

By adding

```
data-form-part="product_form"
```

to the `input/option` field, Then you can get the values.