# How to create custom tab in product admin section in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, admin, adminhtml, magento-2.0.7

I want to create one custom tab in the admin product section for all products and I want to display a custom message. How can I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicated: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/103642/add-new-tab-in-product-edit-page-in-admin-magento-2

Answer (score 5):

#### Update:

I apologize, this answer is working only for **version 2.1** +. I won't delete it, perhaps it can helps somebody (who is using the version 2.1 or greater).

---

Add the modifier in `app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/adminhtml/di.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <virtualType name="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Pool">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="modifiers" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="custom-tab-with-content" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="class" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\CustomTab</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
</config>
```

Create corresponding class `Vendor\Module\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\CustomTab` in `app/code/Vendor/Module/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier/CustomTab.php`:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Locator\LocatorInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\AbstractModifier;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\ArrayManager;
use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Container;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Fieldset;

class CustomTab extends AbstractModifier
{

    const CUSTOM_TAB_INDEX = 'custom_tab';
    const CUSTOM_TAB_CONTENT = 'content';

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Locator\LocatorInterface
     */
    protected $locator;

    /**
     * @var ArrayManager
     */
    protected $arrayManager;

    /**
     * @var UrlInterface
     */
    protected $urlBuilder;

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $meta = [];

    /**
     * @param LocatorInterface $locator
     * @param ArrayManager $arrayManager
     * @param UrlInterface $urlBuilder
     */
    public function __construct(
        LocatorInterface $locator,
        ArrayManager $arrayManager,
        UrlInterface $urlBuilder
    ) {
        $this->locator = $locator;
        $this->arrayManager = $arrayManager;
        $this->urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
    }

    public function modifyData(array $data)
    {
        return $data;
    }

    public function modifyMeta(array $meta)
    {
        $this->meta = $meta;
        $this->addCustomTab();

        return $this->meta;
    }

    protected function addCustomTab()
    {
        $this->meta = array_merge_recursive(
            $this->meta,
            [
                static::CUSTOM_TAB_INDEX => $this->getTabConfig(),
            ]
        );
    }

    protected function getTabConfig()
    {
        return [
            'arguments' => [
                'data' => [
                    'config' => [
                        'label' => __('Custom Tab'),
                        'componentType' => Fieldset::NAME,
                        'dataScope' => '',
                        'provider' => static::FORM_NAME . '.product_form_data_source',
                        'ns' => static::FORM_NAME,
                        'collapsible' => true,
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'children' => [
                static::CUSTOM_TAB_CONTENT => [
                    'arguments' => [
                        'data' => [
                            'config' => [
                                'label' => null,
                                'formElement' => Container::NAME,
                                'componentType' => Container::NAME,
                                'template' => 'ui/form/components/complex',
                                'content' => __('You can write any text here, ') .
                                    ' or html: ' . 
                                    '<h3>Text</h3>' . 
                                    ', or blocks html (using toHtml method).',
                                'sortOrder' => 10,
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                    'children' => [],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }
}
```

Now you can add your content inside the `'content'` section. You can call a block and add its html to the content (using the `toHtml` method). Change it as you wish.

**PS:** do not forget to change the vendor name (**Vendor**) and module name (**Module**) to corresponding own names.

Comment: Can i call product grid in this new tab?

Comment: @chiragdodia Sure, you can load in this tab any content you want

Comment: Can you please tell me how i can load product grid over there?

Comment: I have asked the same question here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/170620/magento-2-add-new-tab-in-product-edit-tab-and-call-product-grid-like-related-p But i didn't get any answer can anybody help me? :(

Answer (score 1):

Just a message? Then you could create a dummy attribute within a new attribute group and use the frontend type "label" to make it not editable.

Or use a custom input renderer, this way you can use your own template and put whatever you like there.