# How to create custom tab in product edit page in magento 2.0.7

Tags: blocks, magento-2.0.7

Magento 2.0.7: How to create a custom module that will add a new tab on product edit page, right under Basic Settings and i want to display my custom phtml page. ?

**view\adminhtml\layout\catalog_product_new.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
  <referenceBlock name="product_tabs">
   <block class="Magento2\Tutorial9\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Tab\Welcome" name="product.welcome" as="custom-tab" >
    <arguments>
     <argument name="config" xsi:type="array">
      <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Product Welcome</item>
      <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
      <item name="opened" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
      <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">2</item>
      <item name="canShow" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
      <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">fieldset</item>
     </argument>
    </arguments>
  </block>
</referenceBlock>
```

**Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Tab\Welcome.php**

```
namespace Magento2\Tutorial9\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Tab;
use Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;
class Welcome extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template{
 protected $_template = 'catalog/product/edit/welcome.phtml';
 protected $_coreRegistry = null;
 public function __construct(
   Context $context,
   Registry $registry,
   array $data = []
 )
 {
    $this->_coreRegistry = $registry;
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}
public function getProduct(){
   return $this->_coreRegistry->registry('current_product');
}   }
```

**view\adminhtml\templates\catalog\product\edit\welcome.phtml**

```
<div class="welcome">
    <?php echo __('Welcome !'); ?>
</div>
```

**etc\module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
   <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
  <module name="Magento2_Tutorial9" setup_version="1.0.0">
</module>
```

**registration.php**

```
<?php \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
'Magento2_Tutorial9',
__DIR__
);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add new tab in product edit page in admin Magento 2](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/103642/add-new-tab-in-product-edit-page-in-admin-magento-2)

Comment: Similar question http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/132774/how-to-create-custom-tab-in-product-admin-section-in-magento-2

Comment: Yes, i tried both option, its not work for me. i am using Magento 2.0.7..

Comment: If you found another question that asks the same but the solution did not work for you, please state this in your question and also explain in detail what you tried. Maybe you made a mistake somewhere and we can't help you if we don't know what you did.

Comment: okay.. i will write my code here