# Magento 2 - Add new tab in product edit tab and call Product Grid like Related Product over there

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, product-grid

I have created custom tab under Product Edit Section using below code

Created file /Vendor/Module/etc/adminhtml/di.xml. In this file below code is included

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<virtualType name="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Pool">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="modifiers" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="custom-tab-with-content" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="class" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\CustomTab</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">30</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>

</config>
```

Created file /Vendor/Module/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier/CustomTab.php. In this file below code is included

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Locator\LocatorInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\AbstractModifier;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\ArrayManager;
use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Container;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Fieldset;

class CustomTab extends AbstractModifier
{
const SAMPLE_FIELDSET_NAME = 'custom_fieldset';
const SAMPLE_FIELD_NAME = 'is_represent';

/**
 * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Locator\LocatorInterface
 */
protected $locator;

/**
 * @var ArrayManager
 */
protected $arrayManager;

/**
 * @var UrlInterface
 */
protected $urlBuilder;

/**
 * @var array
 */
protected $meta = [];

/**
 * @param LocatorInterface $locator
 * @param ArrayManager $arrayManager
 * @param UrlInterface $urlBuilder
 */
public function __construct(
    LocatorInterface $locator,
    ArrayManager $arrayManager,
    UrlInterface $urlBuilder
) {
    $this->locator = $locator;
    $this->arrayManager = $arrayManager;
    $this->urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
}

public function modifyData(array $data)
{
    return array_replace_recursive(
        $data,
        [
            $this->locator->getProduct()->getId() => [
                static::DATA_SOURCE_DEFAULT => [
                    static::SAMPLE_FIELD_NAME => $this->locator->getProduct()->getData(static::SAMPLE_FIELD_NAME),
                ]
            ]
        ]
    );
}

public function modifyMeta(array $meta)
{
    $this->meta = $meta;
    $this->addFieldset();


    return $this->meta;
}

protected function addFieldset()
{
    $this->meta = array_replace_recursive(
        $this->meta,
        [
            static::SAMPLE_FIELDSET_NAME => [
                'arguments' => [
                    'data' => [
                        'config' => [
                            'label' => __('Representing Products'),
                            'componentType' => Fieldset::NAME,
                            'dataScope' => 'data.product',
                            'collapsible' => true,
                            'sortOrder' => 10,
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
                'children' => [
                    'header_container' => $this->getHeaderContainerConfig(10),
                    'headers_container' => $this->getHeaderContainerConfigForProductGrid(30),
                    // Add children here
                ],
            ],
        ]
    );

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get config for header container
 *
 * @param int $sortOrder
 * @return array
 */
protected function getHeaderContainerConfig($sortOrder)
{
    return [
        'arguments' => [
            'data' => [
                'config' => [
                    'label' => null,
                    'formElement' => Container::NAME,
                    'componentType' => Container::NAME,
                    'sortOrder' => $sortOrder,
                    'content' => __('Sample content.'),
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'children' => [
            'sample_container' => $this->getSampleContainer(10),
        ],
    ];
}

protected function getHeaderContainerConfigForProductGrid($sortOrder)
{
    return [
            'arguments' => [
                    'data' => [
                            'config' => [
                                    'label' => null,
                                    'formElement' => Container::NAME,
                                    'componentType' => Container::NAME,
                                    'sortOrder' => $sortOrder,
                                    'content' => __('Sample content.'),
                            ],
                    ],
            ],
            'children' => [
                    'sample_container' => $this->getSampleContainerForProductGrid(30),
            ],
    ];
}

protected function getSampleContainer($sortOrder)
{
    return [
        'arguments' => [
            'data' => [
                'config' => [
                    'label' => null,
                    'formElement' => Fieldset::NAME,
                    'componentType' => Fieldset::NAME,
                    'sortOrder' => $sortOrder,
                    'additionalClasses' => 'admin__field-wide',
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'children' => [
            static::SAMPLE_FIELD_NAME => $this->getSampleFieldConfig(10)
        ],
    ];
}

protected function getSampleContainerForProductGrid($sortOrder)
{
    return [
            'arguments' => [
                    'data' => [
                            'config' => [
                                    'label' => null,
                                    'formElement' => Fieldset::NAME,
                                    'componentType' => Fieldset::NAME,
                                    'sortOrder' => $sortOrder,
                                    'additionalClasses' => 'admin__field-wide',
                            ],
                    ],
            ],
            'children' => [
                    static::SAMPLE_FIELD_NAME => $this->getSampleFieldConfigForProductGrid(30)
            ],
    ];
}

protected function getSampleFieldConfig($sortOrder)
{
    return [
        'arguments' => [
            'data' => [
                'config' => [
                    'label' => __('Enable Multiple Representation Of This Product'),
                    'componentType' => \Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Field::NAME,
                    'formElement' => \Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\Select::NAME,
                    'dataScope' => static::SAMPLE_FIELD_NAME,
                    'options' => $this->getOneinventoryoption(),
                    'dataType' => \Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\DataType\Number::NAME,
                    'sortOrder' => $sortOrder,
                    'required' => true,
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'children' => [],
    ];
}

protected function getSampleFieldConfigForProductGrid($sortOrder)
{
    return [
            'arguments' => [
                    'data' => [
                            'config' => [
                                    'label' => __('Choose Products'),
                                    'formElement' => Container::NAME,
                                    'componentType' => Container::NAME,
                                    'template' => 'ui/form/components/complex',
                                    'content' => 'Product Grid Here',
                                    'sortOrder' => $sortOrder,
                            ],
                    ],
            ],
            'children' => [],
    ];
}



protected function getOneinventoryoption()
{
    $getChooseOptions = [];
    $getChooseOptions[] = [
            'label' => 'Choose Options',
            'value' => '',
    ];
    $getChooseOptions[] = [
            'label' => 'Yes',
            'value' => '1',
    ];
    $getChooseOptions[] = [
            'label' => 'No',
            'value' => '2',
    ];
    return $getChooseOptions;
}
```

}

This is generated below layout

[image]

Now i need to call Related product section like Product grid over there.

How can i achieve this?