# Add tab in magento2?

Tags: product, magento2.2, php-7, tabs

How to add custom tab in product Edit Page in magento2?

I'm  refer https://webkul.com/blog/add-tab-product-page-magento-admin/

But , i can't see tab in product edit page...

If anyone knows please explain me

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can find perfect solution Here :
[Add new tab in product edit page in admin Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/103642/add-new-tab-in-product-edit-page-in-admin-magento-2/209173#209173)

https://webkul.com/blog/add-tab-product-page-magento-admin/ >>> this will not work for magento 2.2.0 and above.

Comment: please check https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/103642/add-new-tab-in-product-edit-page-in-admin-magento-2/209173#209173

Comment: in it i have posted answer.

Comment: please create file 'customdata.phtml' in OX_StockMovements

Comment: Thanks for ur response...Do u know about add grid in that tab

Comment: for that you have to use UI component

Comment: use UI component

Comment: can I use only Ui Component for grid in that tab? @Charvi Parikh